# A secondary nonlinear ODE

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this particular ODE:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{a^2}{y^2}-\frac{b^2}{y^3}$$

Comment: The best questions on this site include not only a statement of the problem, but also the context in which you encountered the problem and a description of what you have tried already. That information makes it possible for the answers to be written in a more personalized manner.

Answer (score 7):

Your ODE is of the form $y''=-V'(y)$, which is typical in mechanics. In your case, the potential is $V(y)=a^2 y^{-1}-\frac{1}{2} b^2 y^{-2}$. Multiply the equation by $y'$ and integrate; this gives $\frac{1}{2} (y')^2 = -V(y) + E$, where $E$ is a constant of integration. Thus $dy/dx = \pm \sqrt{2(E-V(y))}$, which is a separable ODE that can (in principle) be integrated to give $x$ as a function of $y$, and then you can (in principle) invert that relation to get $y$ as a function of $x$.

Answer (score 4):

Multiply both sides of ODE by $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and rearrange terms, we get:
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left[ \frac12 \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 + \frac{a^2}{y} - \frac{b^2}{2y^2}\right] = 0
\implies \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 = 2 E - \frac{2a^2}{y} + \frac{b^2}{y^2}
$$
for some constant $E$. Just for illustration, let's look at case when $E > 0$.
Introduce a parametrization $t \mapsto ( x(t), y(t) )$ by:
$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2E}} y(t)$$
then $y$ satisfies:
$$ ( \frac{dy}{dt} )^2 = y^2 - \frac{a^2}{E} y + \frac{b^2}{2E}
                    = ( y - \frac{a^2}{2E} )^2 + \Omega^2
$$ where $\Omega^2 = \frac{b^2}{2E} - \frac{a^4}{4E^2}$.

For $E \in ( \frac{a^4}{2b^2}, \infty )$, $\Omega$ is real and the ODE has a solution:
$$\begin{align}
         & y(t) = \frac{a^2}{2E} \pm \Omega \sinh t\\
\implies & x(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2E}}\left( \frac{a^2}{2E} t \pm \Omega \cosh t\right)
\end{align}
$$
For $E \in ( 0, \frac{a^4}{2b^2} )$, $\Omega = i|\Omega|$ is imaginary and the ODE has a solution:
$$\begin{align}
         & y(t) = \frac{a^2}{2E} \pm |\Omega| \cosh t\\
\implies & x(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2E}}\left( \frac{a^2}{2E} t \pm |\Omega| \sinh t\right)
\end{align}
$$
The case for $E < 0$ is similar except you get solutions involving $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

Maple comes up with the implicit solutions
$$-C_{{1}}\sqrt {-2\,{a}^{2}y \left( x \right) {C_{{1}}}^{2}+{b}^{2}{C_{
{1}}}^{2}+  y \left( x \right)   ^{2}}+{a}^{2}{C_{{1}}}^{
3}\ln  \left( C_{{1}} \right) -{a}^{2}{C_{{1}}}^{3}\ln  \left( -{a}^{2
}{C_{{1}}}^{2}+y \left( x \right) +\sqrt {-2\,{a}^{2}y \left( x
 \right) {C_{{1}}}^{2}+{b}^{2}{C_{{1}}}^{2}+  y \left( x
 \right)   ^{2}} \right) -x-C_{{2}}=0
$$
and
$$
C_{{1}}\sqrt {-2\,{a}^{2}y \left( x \right) {C_{{1}}}^{2}+{b}^{2}{C_{{
1}}}^{2}+  y \left( x \right)   ^{2}}-{a}^{2}{C_{{1}}}^{3
}\ln  \left( C_{{1}} \right) +{a}^{2}{C_{{1}}}^{3}\ln  \left( -{a}^{2}
{C_{{1}}}^{2}+y \left( x \right) +\sqrt {-2\,{a}^{2}y \left( x
 \right) {C_{{1}}}^{2}+{b}^{2}{C_{{1}}}^{2}+  y \left( x
 \right)   ^{2}} \right) -x-C_{{2}}=0
$$
where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are arbitrary constants.

Comment: Thx, but how we solve this by hand?

Comment: Don't except Robert to post you the entire solution