# Solution of $y''=\frac{K}{y^2}$ with $K$ a constant.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve 
$$
y''=\frac{K}{y^2}
$$
where $K$ is a non-zero constant.

My attempt :

- Lagrange method i.e.  $z=\frac{y'}{y}$ but it's look harder.
- Multiplying both sides by $y'$, then integration but it doesn't look better.
- I tried to let $y=y(0)(cos(z))^s$ but is ineffective

Moreover, the equation is nonlinear, we know nothing about the finiteness or countability of the dimension of the solution space,

Thank you in advance for you help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to obtain an explicit solution $y=y(t)$ to your equation (it is better to name the independent variable $t$, not $x$, as I will explain below). But you can write a nice parametrization for the graphs of the solutions in the $(t,y)$ plane. Fot $K<0$, these are famous curves called cycloids.

Your equation is a special case of a class of 2nd order ODE for a single function $y(t)$, of the form $\ddot y=f(y)$, called "Newton's Second Law" (the dots denote derivatives with respect to $t$; in your case $f(y)=K/y^2$), for which a good trick has been invented, called "Conservation of Energy".

The trick: Let us find a function $V(y)$ such that $f(y)=-V'(y)$ (a prime denotes derivative with respect to $y$). That is, just integrate $f(y)$ with respect to $y$. $V$ is well-defined up to an additive constant, just pick any (in your case $V=K/y$ will do).

Theorem ("Conservation of Energy"): Let $y(t)$ be a solution of $\ddot y=-V'(y)$. Then $E=(\dot y)^2/2+V(y)$ is a constant function (of $t$). Conversely, any solution $y(t)$ of $(\dot y)^2/2+V(y)=const.$ is a solution of $\ddot y=-V'(y)$.

The proof is immediate, just show that $dE/dt=0$, using the chain rule.

Now the equation $E=(\dot y)^2/2+V(y)=c$ (where $c$ is an arbitrary constant) is a first order separable ODE,  which, if you are lucky (very rarely),  can be solved explicitly. Even if you cannot solve it explicitly, you can usually draw the curves $E(y,v)=v^2/2+V(y)=c$ in the $(y,v)$ plane (called the "phase plane" of the DE), and get valuable information on the solutions of the original equation $\ddot y=f(y)$.

In your case, the phase curves $E(y,v)=c$ are quite easy to draw and the pictures you get, for distinct values of $K$, are quite nice and instructive (please try it).

As for solving explicitly in your case  the differential equation  $(\dot y)^2/2+K/y=c$,  you are "half lucky". After applying the Conservation of Energy trick, you end up, as was shown by another answer, with 
$$t=\pm\int_{y(0)}^{y(t)}\frac{dy}{\sqrt{2(c-\frac{K}{y})}},$$
which is messy to solve explicitly  for $y(t)$  (impossible with elementary functions). Fortunately,  there is a more elementary way out, with a pleasant surprise, known to few (in my experience; I have not seen it in any standard ODE textbook, but I am sure it is somewhere).

I will sketch just one case, $K=-1$ (Newton's gravitational attraction law), $y(0)=1/2,$ $\dot y(0)=0$, hence $c=-2$ (you will see in a minute  why I picked $y(0)=1/2$).  Make the substitution $y=[\cos^2(\theta/2)]/2$ in the  integral above. You get, after some fiddling, $y(\theta)=(1+\cos \theta)/4,$ $t=(\theta+\sin\theta))/4$.

This is a parametric representation  of a curve in the $(t,y)$ plane called a cycloid, the curve you get by placing  a  disc of radius $1/4$ on the $t$ axis, its center at $(0,1/4)$, and tracing the point on the disc initially at $(0,1/2)$ as the disc rolls without slipping along the $t$ axis. For other initial conditions and values of $K<0$ you get a curve that is obtained from this one by some stretching  along the $t$ and $y$ axis (at different rates), and some translation along the $t$ axis. You can check that for $K=-1$,  $\dot y(0)=0$ and $y(0)>0$, only for $y(0)=1/2$  there is such a nice "rolling" description of the graph of $y(t)$.

Another nice feature here is that we see that by appropriate time reparametrization $t=t(\theta)$, we can extend quite naturally solutions to the equation "beyond collision" ($y=0$). This is the basis of a standard trick in celestial mechanics, sometime called "the Levi-Civita regularization" of collision orbits.

I hope all this is helpful and that you can fill-in the details (especially for  $K>0$).

Answer (score 2):

***Hint:***$$y''=\frac{dy'}{dx}=\frac{dy'}{dy}.\frac{dy}{dx}=y'.\frac{dy'}{dy}=\frac{K}{y^2}$$ then separation of $y$ and $y'$ i.e. 
$$\int y'.dy'=\int\frac{K}{y^2}dy
\\\frac{(y')^2}{2}=\frac{-K}{y}+c
\\ y'=\pm\sqrt{2c-2\frac{K}{y}}
\\\int\frac{dy}{\pm\sqrt{2c-2\frac{K}{y}}}=\int dx$$

Comment: @Nico i have edited it, you can now integrate again separate variables x and y

Comment: You can also refer to essentially the same problem solved here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297385/solving-yx-fracky2?rq=1